# Как указать ссылку на файл, скачанный в процессе работы программы, в WevView?

Tags: android, html, ссылки

Здравствуйте!
   Есть файлы которые я скачиваю динамически(Перед началом работы программы их не существует).
    Файлы записываю во внутреннее хранилище программы (`internal storage`), то есть в `data/data/-packageName--/files/someFile.someExtention`
После записи файла, я беру его имя и загружаю в `webview` такой `HTML` код:

```
someMethod (String someFile.someExtention){
....
    String html = "<video x-webkit-airplay=\"allow\" controls=\"\" alt=\"Live Stream\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" src=\"FILENAME\"></video>";
    mWebView.loadData(html,"text/html", "UTF-8");
...
}
```

Если в `src`, вместо `FILENAME`, указать внешний файл (хранящийся в интернете, например http://www.someSite.com/someFile.someExtention) все работает как надо. 
А как указать на скачанный файл? (побывал вместо `FILENAME` -  `file:///data/data/-packageName--/files/someFile.someExtention , someFile.someExtention ,files/someFile.someExtention, data/data/-packageName--/files/someFile.someExtention , file:///files/someFile.someExtention, file:///someFile.someExtention` - ни один вариант не работает.  `someFile.someExtention`  дописывается  через

```
  "+ someFile.someExtention +"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно использовать метод `loadDataWithBaseURL`, когда необходим доступ к файлам или запускать скрипты со страниц :

```
        mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

А путь к Вашему файлу можно добыть так:

```
       yourDownloadedFile.toURI.toString();
```

получится строка вида:

```
     file:/data/data/-packageName--/files/someFile.someExtention
```